# Laravel Change php object on ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

From Controller I'm passing a php object
**Controller**

```
 $object = Object::where('id', $id)->first();
 $object2 = Object::where('id', $id2)->first();
 return view('obj_spec',compact(['object','object2']));
```

I'm able to render the blade template using $object->attribute, I have a 
**select tag** in that blade

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" onchange="getval(this);">
<option selected>{{$object->name}}</option>
<option value="{{$object->name}}">{{$object->model}}</option>
<option value="{{$object2->name}}">{{$object2->model}}</option>
```

**Ajax**

```
function getval(sel)
{
alert(sel.value);
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$.ajax({
            url:'/set_object',
            type:'POST',
            data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, obj:sel.value},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function( data ) {
            console.log(data['obj_name']);

                }
            });

}
```

Now on change of select, I want to change the php object stored in $object 
I don't want to use cookie. Or is there any approach of solving this ?

Comment: Interesting reading to do [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

Comment: What's the alternative approach ?

Comment: For now I'm using `window.location.href = "localhost/objects/"+data['id'];` . Is there any way to avoid redirect ?

Comment: I suppose you have to overwrite `#inputGroupSelect01` with the rusult of `/set_object`. If you don't understand wht this means, you have to read more tutorials on Ajax. This question really looks like "too broad".